# How to send app to end of App Switcher list?

Tags: macos, application-switcher

When you use <kbd>command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>tab ⇥</kbd> to change to another application in App Switcher, that app is moved to the front of the stack.

Is there a way to send an app to the tail of the stack, other than the brute-force technique of switching to every running app except that one?

Comment: app switcher on mac, phone ?